# INNER JOIN Error converting to data type int

Tags: sql, ssms

I’m looking at doing a very simple JOIN using SSMS and consistently coming across the below error.
My understanding is I need to use the CAST function but I cannot get it to work.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'quagmire, glenn' to data
> type int.

This error shows I’m getting an error trying to convert a string to an int.
I believe this is because the Staff_ID and Manager fields are INT and I’m trying to replace the Manager with the name value from the tblLUManager table.

I’m very new to SQL but I have did some reading and attempted a few variations of the below but to no avail.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I’m eager to learn.

```
SELECT 
    jobID, Manager, Datapoint, Description
    FROM test.dbo.tblJoinTest
    INNER JOIN tblLUManager ON tblJoinTest.Manager = cast(tblLUManager.name as nvarchar)
```

[tables attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvR6B.png)

Comment: Problems like this usually indicate your tables have inconsistent data types. Or, you're joining using wrong columns. You can't expect `'quagmire, glenn'` to be equal to an integer _column_.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join on the `staff_id` instead of trying to `cast` the name of the manager.

```
SELECT 
    jobID, 
    Name as ManagerName
    Datapoint, 
    Description
  FROM test.dbo.tblJoinTest
  INNER JOIN tblLUManager 
    ON tblJoinTest.Manager = staff_id;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response.

While this code does work it does not result in the outcome i want.
Im looking as displaying the value of "name" instead of "Staff_ID"